# HelloSign gives 'Invalid custom field' error

Tags: php, symfony, hellosign-api

I am using a HelloSign template and passing data to it using HelloSign PHP SDK on a Symfony project.

I used the same API ID in the template to pass data to the template but I am getting 'Invalid custom field: b1_fullname' error.

Here's my code,

```
$client = new \HelloSign\Client('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
$hs_request = new \HelloSign\TemplateSignatureRequest;
$hs_request->enableTestMode();
$hs_request->setTemplateId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$hs_request->setTitle('Test');
$hs_request->setSubject('Test');
$hs_request->setMessage('Test');
$hs_request->setSigner('Client', 'aaa@bbb.com', 'AAA');
$hs_request->setCustomFieldValue('b1_fullname', 'AAA BBB');

$hs_response = $client->sendTemplateSignatureRequest($hs_request);
```

Here's how the template API field ID looks like.

[image]

Comment: you must set the setCustomFieldValue before sending request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When setting up the template, you'll need to set "Who fills this out?" to "Me (when sending)" so the API knows the expect a value for the custom field:
[Template Field Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a16mZ.png)

Comment: I don't see "Me (when sending)"  option in the drop-down? Did this feature change in the template editor? I spend all day trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
$client = new \HelloSign\Client('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
$hs_request = new \HelloSign\TemplateSignatureRequest;
$hs_request->enableTestMode();
$hs_request->setTemplateId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$hs_request->setTitle('Test');
$hs_request->setSubject('Test');
$hs_request->setMessage('Test');
$hs_request->setSigner('Client', 'aaa@bbb.com', 'AAA');

//firstly set the setCustomeFieldValue
$hs_request->setCustomFieldValue('b1_fullname', 'AAA BBB');

$hs_response = $client->sendTemplateSignatureRequest($hs_request);
```

Comment: Sorry I have mixed up the lines in the question. I moved it before the response and corrected the question.